# How hackers can penetrate our smart contract function calls?

Tags: solidity, transactions, hack, method

I used this code in a smart contract method on Polygon blockchain:

```
function withdraw() public {
    iERC20 tether = iERC20(0xc2132D05D31c914a87C6611C10748AEb04B58e8F);
    tether.transfer(msg.sender, tether.balanceOf(address(this)));
}
```

Note: I forgot to make this function `onlyOwner`.

At the beginning there was 50 Tethers in the smart contract. When I called this method, 0 tether transferred to my wallet and the smart contract became empty!

I traced the transaction and wondered to see this consecutive transactions in the smart contract at one block:

[image]

The last destination at the top is my wallet and both of the other destinations accounts are contracts:

[0xa8f4098f0c9b5b3ab59844d0d5e070f8f7524ec9](https://polygonscan.com/address/0xa8f4098f0c9b5b3ab59844d0d5e070f8f7524ec9)

[0x4bfd2181be8fa2f6702dee41a46baabeb5d3dd3d](https://polygonscan.com/address/0x4bfd2181be8fa2f6702dee41a46baabeb5d3dd3d)

Note that the destination 0xa8f4... is marked as instant withdrawals and was instantly discharged.

How hackers can aware this vulnerability of a method and send their transactions instantly before my transaction? Are they in the Polygonscan organization that receive our sent transactions?

Note: I sent my transaction via Metamask wallet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like what you experienced is a **frontrunning** attack.

**Frontrunning** is a type of transaction manipulation where an attacker exploits the predictability of a transaction's execution to their advantage. In your case, the attacker likely monitored the blockchain for pending transactions and quickly submitted their own transaction to execute before yours.

Here's how the attack likely unfolded:

1. Your transaction to withdraw Tether from the smart contract was broadcasted to the network.
2. An attacker monitoring pending transactions saw your transaction and quickly submitted their own transaction to withdraw Tether from the same smart contract but with a higher gas price.
3. Miners prioritize transactions with higher gas prices, so the attacker's transaction got included in the block before yours.
4. The attacker's transaction emptied the smart contract, leaving no Tether for your transaction to withdraw.

Regarding your question about whether hackers are affiliated with **Polygonscan** or similar blockchain explorers:

It's highly unlikely that hackers are affiliated with blockchain explorers like Polygonscan. These platforms merely provide a user interface to interact with the blockchain and explore transactions. They don't have the ability to manipulate transactions or influence their execution. Instead, attackers use various tools and monitoring techniques to identify and exploit vulnerabilities like frontrunning.

Comment: How can attackers access the transaction mempool? Is it possible for us to monitor pending transactions?

Comment: @AlirezaZojaji, Attackers can access the transaction mempool by running their own node or using public blockchain explorers. We can monitor pending transactions through node APIs, third-party APIs, blockchain explorers, and by listening for smart contract events.